# Splitting Token for a Simplified Processing Within a TreeListener

Tags: antlr4

In my ANTLR4 grammar I'm using many rules like this one:

```
subheadline
    : SUBHEADLINE newlines
    ;
```

In my lexer file SUBHEADLINE ist defined as:

```
SUBHEADLINE
    : '##' (~[\r\n])+? '##'
    ;
```

The resulting tree looks fine. But in the processing I need to remove both '##' portions of the matched token. Of course that's possible, but it would be awesome if I can move them into different tokens.

I tried something like this:

```
subheadline
    : SUB_START_END SUBHEADLINE SUB_START_END newlines
    ;

SUB_START_END
    : '##'
    ;

SUBHEADLINE
    : (~[\r\n])+?
    ;
```

But then the input don't get recognized any more. For example this string:

### Subheadline Text ## results in the following error:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input '## Subheadline Text ##' expecting '##'
```

I already tried something like that:

```
SUBHEADLINE
    : (~[\r\n#])+?
    ;
```

But the error is still the same. I thought I can simply move those start and end characters into one or two dedicated tokens.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No real reason for generating additional tokens. The token type identifies the content as has having matched `##` strings. So, just need to implement a custom token where the `getText()` method switches on the token type and, for a `SUBHEADLINE` type, strips leading and trailing `#`s. Add a custom token factory to the lexer to generate the custom tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But in fact the custom token factory has to do the same - stripping out those '##' for example - as I have to do in my listener? Is there any benefit over the token factory compared to the listener solution?